# Atualizar apenas 1 item dentro do no do firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-database

Eu tenho o seguinte nó no firebase:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dentro dese nó eu preciso acessar o valor usuario e altera-lo, para fazer isso estou utilizando esse código:

```
                   firebaseSenha = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase().child("usuarios").child(identificadorUsuarioLogado);

                firebaseSenha.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Usuario usuarioSenha = dataSnapshot.getValue(Usuario.class);

                        String senhaRecuperada = senha.getText().toString();

                        firebaseSenha = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase();
                        firebaseSenha = firebaseSenha.child("usuarios").child(identificadorUsuarioLogado);

                        Usuario usuario = new Usuario();

                        usuario.setSenha(senhaRecuperada);

                        firebaseSenha.setValue(usuario);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Porem esses código está fazendo com que todos os outros campos dentro do nó se apaguem e sobre somente o valor senha alterado, como faço para alterar somente o valor da senha, sem deletar os outros.

Apos executar o código ele fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você lê em inglês? [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48324639/update-item-in-firebase-android) tem uma resposta para sua pergunta.

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode atualizar apenas o atributo senha

ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase().child("usuarios").child(identificadorUsuarioLogado).child("senha").setValue("sua senha")

Answer (score 0):

Opa, tudo bem!?

nao há a necessidade de vc alterar todo mundo, vc pode apenas dar um `setValue()` apenas no atributo que deseja alterar.

```
firebaseSenha = firebaseSenha.child("usuarios").child(identificadorUsuarioLogado);

//sua logica.... e agora vc poderá setar apenas a senha.

firebaseSenha.child("senha").setValue(senhaRecuperada);
```